# How to write appropriate typeguard in this scenario

Tags: typescript

In the following example, how could I use a typeguard on the `dictionaryHasEntry` function in order to infer that `dictionnary.get(key)` is not `undefined` ?

```js
const dictionary = new Map<string, any[]>()

function dictionaryHasEntry(key:string) { // Should infer that dictionnary.get(key) is of type any[]
  return !!dictionary.get(key)
}


function addValueToExistingEntry(key:string, value: any) {
  if(dictionaryHasEntry(key)){
    const existingEntry = dictionary.get(key) // existingEntry should be infered as of type any[]
    existingEntry.push(value) // Don't want to use "existingEntry!" here.
  }
}
```

Code example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2FB4CGAnAnjAvDMAUwHcYBZNABwB5oMEwBzAGhjTCwG0BdAPgAoAlAChhAMwCuYZKjDwkKdNgASaCAFEwUbPwDWhLAC46DRoJgBvGAHprMAMoALEBIA2cGAzGEMMKI7RYRBlwMEwsADpGQig9A3MECBgQMT8sSkI2Dh5hGBgMGIkMOQBCEuDFMOwomLisEQBfUXEpELk0ODgANTRXCUIAFRB1AA9ElCZNbSw6421TVgA3Xv7DLPrLXM8xfgrZcNUNLR19esELLbzQSFhCMehTKew8eTbwmtjT81sYO-HH444CDONweABGmS8PkIHjUyVSUHSmXYXG4l1%209wmjCekUoEmB-GWfUI3zsABFwAByWDEdiwKAgGD4zIAIhKLJZMEc0IiWyaTSAA)

Comment: If `key` is just of type `string` then there's nothing you can do since the compiler won't be able to remember that you're using the *same* key in the `dictionaryHasEntry()` call and in the `get()` call.  You don't want the compiler to think that *all* `string` keys have values in the map.  You'd need to narrow down `key` from `string` to some string literal type for that to begin to work.  Why not just call `get()` and check it for `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least crazy way to approach this is to just call `get()` and then use the return value of `undefined` to indicate that the entry does not exist.  If your map value type could possibly be `undefined`, that would be a problem, but `undefined` is not assignable to `any[]`, so it's a reasonable way to distinguish presence from absence:

```
const dictionary = new Map<string, any[]>()

function addValueToExistingEntry(key: string, value: any) {
  const existingEntry = dictionary.get(key);
  if (existingEntry !== undefined) {
    existingEntry.push(value)
  }
}
```

---

If you want to start using [type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to narrow the map to a type with a definite value at the given key, you need to use lots of generics and specifically have the key be of a type narrower than `string`, like a generic [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string` or like a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types).  Like this:

```
function dictionaryHasKey<
  M extends Map<string, any>,
  K extends string
>(dict: M, key: K): dict is { get(k: K): M extends Map<any, infer V> ? V : never } & M {
  return dict.has(key);
}
```

And then your original code will work:

```
function hmmAddValueToExistingEntry<K extends string>(key: K, value: any) {
  if (dictionaryHasKey(dictionary, key)) {
    const existingEntry = dictionary.get(key);
    existingEntry.push(value);
  }
}
```

But that's a lot of work and advanced type-system hoop jumping compared to just checking `existingEntry` for being `undefined`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=3.9.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2FB4CGAnAnjAvDMAUwHcYBZNABwB5oMEwBzAGhjTCwG0BdAPgAoAlAChhAMwCuYZKjBs4cAGpoANhMIAVEAFEAHgmgNG2sFGz8A1oSwAuGHSOsAbqvV32WQTADewmDFBIWEJ9QyYTMxx8RBl0bAA6RkIoS2tBAG4-GAQxGH4QgxRw02wYAEJcfCk4QjEGQjgvX39-ArDjEqx4ygkIAAt+FzVCEX8AXxhhMdFxKVi5GJQ4rAAJNAgAaWtqLLIYEKhCMDgIcipaM0c2Dl5mLI393UPj04cmYQFFuzJWK1sYDaCOyLbKnbwwJIpCx2QHfR7PE5nGgeVgMMSEDAwRS8GAAfixMDsRCcGJgEwAZOQfFkMMkJBgFkgoPE+utUp5MtNZtIlnI+gBbfkAQQUymGWj0hSMEWw1AeByOiLejAEfxhzlchHcHCaWRyeUWskwq3WWyw-ENy1+aV1LQC4GgjylxUieHgTKNCUh7IyWVaoSKHUi3V6AyG6l94ymQA)

Answer (score 0):

So first of all I would change the name of the method, because it implies the value is existing, although the undefined check needs to be performed inside of the method. In addition, Typescript maps support the `has` method, which returns you a boolean if a map contains a key. I would do it like that.

```
function addValueToExistingEntry(key:string, value: any) {
    if (dictionary.has(key)) {
      const existingEntry = dictionary.get(key);
      if (existingEntry) { 
        existingEntry.push(value);
        dictionary.set((key), existingEntry);
      }
    } else {
      dictionary.set(key, value)
    }
}
```